# Upload file and attach it to contentDocument

Tags: contentversion, contentdocument, upload

I'm trying to develop a functionality that upload files and attach it to my opportunity ContentDocument (and not attachment) like my standard component do . I'm wondering when i'm saving my uploaded file in contentdocument , if i should create a version in contentversion for that file or how does it really work , in another world how i create my contentdocument object ?

I'm a beginer in salesforce and the relationship between contentdocument and contentversion is not that clear to me.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Yes, you are heading good way, content Version is actual place where Blob files is stored, you should find some more info on various forums, but this is good way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Whenever you insert a ContentVersion, Automatically a version get inserted for the file.The number increments with each version of the document, for example, 1, 2, 3.

Use ContentVersion object to create, query, retrieve, search, edit, and update a specific version of a Salesforce CRM Content document or Salesforce file. Use the ContentDocument object to retrieve, query, update, and delete the latest version of a document, but not a content pack, in a library or a Salesforce file.

You cannot insert ContentDocument directly, As soon as you insert ContentVersion, a ContentDocument get inserted behind the scene.

**Supported Calls for ContentDocument**

> delete(), describeLayout()describeSObjects(), query(), retrieve(),
>   search(), undelete(), update()

Use ContentDocument object to retrieve, query, update, and delete the latest version of a document, but not a content pack, in a library or a Salesforce file. Use the ContentVersion object to create, query, retrieve, search, edit, and update a specific version of a Salesforce CRM Content document or Salesforce file.

for inserting a ContentVersion, You can use below piece of code:-

```
      ContentVersion ContVerFile = new ContentVersion();
            ContVerFile.VersionData = Blob.valueOf('string');
            ContVerFile.Title = 'title'; 
            ContVerFile.ContentLocation= 's';
            ContVerFile.PathOnClient='title.csv';
      insert ContVerFile;
```

In order to link the file with any record, You need to insert Contentdocumentlink with linlkentityid equals to the id of the record.

Use Contentdocumentlink object to query the locations where a file is shared or query which files are linked to a particular location. For example, the following query returns a particular document shared with a Chatter group:

```
SELECT ContentDocument.title FROM ContentDocumentLink WHERE ContentDocumentId = '069D00000000so2' AND LinkedEntityId = '0D5000000089123'
```

Insertion:-

```
Id conDoc = [SELECT ContentDocumentId FROM ContentVersion WHERE Id =:ContVerFile.Id].ContentDocumentId;
                ContentDocumentLink cDe = new ContentDocumentLink();
                cDe.ContentDocumentId = conDoc;
                cDe.LinkedEntityId = parentId;
                cDe.ShareType = 'I';
                cDe.Visibility = 'AllUsers';
                insert cDe;
```

You can read more about the Special Access Rules, fields definition and its usage here:-

1. [ContentVersion](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_contentversion.htm)
2. [ContentDocument](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_contentdocument.htm)
3. [ContentDocumentLink](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_contentdocumentlink.htm)